# Odd X server error with ffmpeg

Tags: linux, bash, ffmpeg, cron, x11

I am building a weather data acquisition system. One of the things I would like to do would be to animate the satellite data that is arriving every 15 minutes. In fact, I have already devised a script (called `animate`) that successfully joins eight hours worth of PNG images into an AVI video file. This runs fine when run manually from the terminal.

Unfortunately, the same cannot be said when run from my (as in my user, not root) crontab.

Below is the cron job that I mentioned:

```bash
1,16,31,46 * * * * /home/daniella/bin/anim_all > /home/daniella/logs/anim_all.log 2>&1
```

`anim_all` simply calls animate for each distinct data product:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
set -x
cd /home/daniella/data/imager

rm -rf HRIT_MSG3_*.avi

animate HRIT_MSG3_CTT
animate HRIT_MSG3_IR108
animate HRIT_MSG3_VIS006
animate HRIT_MSG3_WV062
```

And animate itself calls `ffmpeg`.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

set -x
cd /home/daniella/data/imager
product=$1
hl="$product.8hl"

declare -i i=0
for file in $(cat $hl); do
    link=$(printf "images%02d.png" $i)
    ln -sf $file $link
    i=$((i+1))
    echo $i
done

ffmpeg -sameq -r 15 -i images%02d.png $product.avi
rm -rf images*.png
```

Just to be clear, the .8hl file is simply a list of PNG file paths that refer to that last 8 hours of data. Since there is new data every 15 minutes, that is a text file with 32 lines. Finally, this is the error that is returned when examining anim_all.log (referred in the crontab) file.

```bash
+ animate HRIT_MSG3_CTT
animate: unable to open X server `' @ animate.c/AnimateImageCommand/365.
+ animate HRIT_MSG3_IR108
animate: unable to open X server `' @ animate.c/AnimateImageCommand/365.
+ animate HRIT_MSG3_VIS006
animate: unable to open X server `' @ animate.c/AnimateImageCommand/365.
+ animate HRIT_MSG3_WV062
animate: unable to open X server `' @ animate.c/AnimateImageCommand/365.
```

Please note that `anim_all` works fine, when called manually from the terminal. This error exists only when called by cron. I would imagine that this has to do with environment variables, but I have sourced my `.bashrc` inside the script to no prevail.

EDIT - 
Investigating the `animate.c` file itself (see the full [code here](http://www.imagemagick.org/api/MagickWand/animate_8c_source.html)), at lines 365-368, there is this:

```C
if (display == (Display *) NULL)
    ThrowAnimateException(XServerError,"UnableToOpenXServer",
    XDisplayName(server_name));
(void) XSetErrorHandler(XError);
```

In response, I have attempted to export the `$DISPLAY` variable to 127.0.0.0:0 in the `animate` script, but this has not worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling the ImageMagick command `animate` instead of your script. In `anim_all` you should be using the full path to the `animate` script.

```
/full/path/to/animate HRIT_MSG3_CTT
```

For good measure I'd change the name of animate to eliminate further confusion.

The error tips us off to what was happening. To start with ImageMagick's `animate` requires an X display, as it has a GUI. Furthermore, it says that the error is comming from `animate.c/AnimateImageCommand/365`, which is of course referring to [this](http://www.imagemagick.org/api/MagickWand/animate_8c.html#acdf5255455a6f2171d9a9d01bb9bc7e3) file.

Comment: Thanks! I should have caught on, since I myself linked to the same file. I implemented the changes, and now everything works perfectly.:D